# How do I find my last day of employment?

Tags: termination

I recently got fired from my job in Kentucky. My landlord needs to know what my last day of employment was, how do I get this information?

My landlord needs something on paper showing my last day, something more official than me simply telling her the date.

Comment: The day you got fired. I'm pretty sure I'd remember a day like that...

Comment: yes i remember tthe day i got fired she needs something on paper saying my last day of employment

Comment: Is paper required because she can't "trust" (legally) your word alone? Would the word of the company work if your landlord called HR?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere some landlords have policies and/or lease clauses that will allow the tenant to terminate the lease mid-term without penalty if they lose their job, or their employer relocates them more than X miles away. It's conceivable that the poster needs to break their lease here.

Comment: Did they not give you an experience letter .... oh, wait wrong country. :)

Answer (score 4):

The HR department of any company is required to keep track of records like this for a set amount of time. Edit: Check this link out. It about the [record keeping requirments](https://www.eeoc.gov/employers/recordkeeping.cfm). Though this is the U.S. Requirements I would imagine it is close to that of other developed countries and I am sure there is a site that lays out the record keeping rules for each of them.

All things related to your time at that company should be recorded and available to HR. Your start date, end date, Job title and so on.

Just call the HR department and request the records. You may need to verify you are who you way you are, I have never not been able to get this kind of info.